# Using insert query CI PHP Mysql Ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, codeigniter, xampp

Iam new on using Code Igniter. I want to use a custom insert query, reason is i want to use uuid() on my query and Im not sure what part of my code is wrong. I echoed the query, it seems that the custom query is correct, I tried it executing directly on my phpmyadmin. Please help me. TIA!

SSL.js

```
$('#btnSaveSSL').click(function(){
    var SelMerch = $('#merchantList option:selected').val();
    var SSLCert = $('#SSLCert').val();
    var SSLPath = $('#file_SSL').val();
    var ReqDate = $('#ReqDate').val();
    var ExpDate = $('#ExpDate').val();
    var Requester = $('#Requester').val();
    $.ajax({
        type:"post",
        url: baseurl + "SSLController/AddSSLRecord",
        data: {'SelMerch': SelMerch,
                'SSLCert': SSLCert,
                'SSLPath': SSLPath,
                'ReqDate': ReqDate,
                'ExpDate': ExpDate,
                'Requester': Requester},
        success:function(response) 
        {
            alert(response);
        },
        error: function(response) 
        {
            console.log(response.d);
        }
    });
});
```

SSLController.php

```
function AddSSLRecord(){
    $SelMerch = $this->input->post('SelMerch');
    $SSLCert = $this->input->post('SSLCert');
    $SSLPath = $this->input->post('SSLPath');
    $ReqDate = $this->input->post('ReqDate');
    $ExpDate = $this->input->post('ExpDate');
    $Requester = $this->input->post('Requester');
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO tbl_user(SSLID,
                                MerchantID,
                                SSL_CertName,
                                SSL_CertPath,
                                RequestDate,
                                ExpirationDate,
                                Requester)  
            VALUES (    uuid()
                     ,' .$this->db->escape($SelMerch).
                    ','.$this->db->escape($SSLCert).
                    ','.$this->db->escape($SSLPath).
                    ','.$this->db->escape($ReqDate).
                    ','.$this->db->escape($ExpDate).
                    ','.$this->db->escape($Requester).')';
     $this->SSLModel->CreateSSLRecord($sql);

    // echo "success" . $sql;
}
```

SSLModel.php

```
public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
    }
function CreateSSLRecord($sql){
        $this->db->insert("tbl_ssl", $sql);  
    }
```

Comment: If you are new to CodeIgniter, I strongly suggest you read the user guide on the use of $this->db->insert('table_name',$data). https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#id7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your custom query is correct and it is working fine so you may consider using this:

```
$this->db->query($your_query);
```

But don't forget to sanitize your inputs before using this method.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use the *Query Builder* provided by **Codeigniter**:

```
$data = array(
 'rowname1' => 'value1',
 'rowname2' => 'value2',
 'rowname3' => 'value3' 
);

$this->db->insert('yourtablename',$data);
```